# PHP Add Days To Date

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Alright, so I'm working on a licensing system, and I'm very new to working with PHP.
I'd like to retrieve the number of days a license key has, then add that to the current day.
My code,

```
$expire = $tags['exp_time']; //EXPIRATION_DATE_DAYS
$expDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expDate = strtotime($expDate);
$expDate = $expDate + ((24 * 60 * 60)*($expire));
$expDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $expDate);
```

I can retrieve the number of days just fine by the way, it's just creating the timestamp in a DATE-TIME format.

Any help/suggestions will greatly be appreciated.
I've also tried,

- date_modify(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime();                  // Create datetime object representing now
$date->modify("+ $expires days");        // Add $expires days to it
$expDate = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Format it
```

If you're running PHP 5.4+ you can shorten it to a one-liner:

```
$expDate = (new DateTime())->modify("+ $expires days")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

FYI, this code:

```
$expDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expDate = strtotime($expDate);
```

can be written as:

```
$expDate = time();
```

`time()` returns the current unix timestamp which is all `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` does.

Answer (score 2):

Another one-liner, using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon):

```
$expDate = Carbon::now()->addDays($expire)->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add days to a date using this code:

```
$ExpDate = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("+".$expire." day", date("Y-m-d g:i:s")));
```

Make sure `$expire` is a of type int.  This code will return the date when the license expires.