# How can I get the batch end date in Y-M-D format using php

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do I get the end date in Y M D format when I have my batch start date as 01/03/2017 and total days as 56 days.

```
date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, $days));
```

I tried this,Here the days as my total days.But it is not working. please help some one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Add Days To Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169950/php-add-days-to-date)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very easy by [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$start_date = '01/03/2017';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date + ' +' . $days . ' days')); //$days after $start_date
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01/03/2017"));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+56 days', strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Below is the code to change date format**

```
   $originalDate = date_create("yourdate");
   $newDate =   date_format($originalDate,"Y/m/d");
```

**U can refer below link also**

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp

**If are having 2 inputs for date then u can use date_diff**
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp